# Hubot use github webhook

Tags: github, webhooks, hubot

I am totally new in `hubot`, and I am stuck at something seems easy.

I want to use this [plugin](https://github.com/yujiosaka/hubot-github-comment-notifier) to send messages to users via `slack` when they have a mention comment or there's a comment on their pull requests.

But I have some trouble setting on Github `webhook`, how to fill in this form correctly? What's the `hubot_url` should be? If I test on my local machine, should the URL be `http://localhost:port/hubot/github-pull-request?room=ROOM&only-mentioned=1`? 
[image]

And what's the port of `hubot` if I test it on my local machine? It seems I fill it with wrong data.  The delivery failed and got a service timeout error.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend setting up `hubot` on a public IP like AWS or heroku. If you insist on a local test environment, there are instructions here https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/

Comment: In future, I will push it into a cloud host. Now I just want to test on local machine, so I thought there's a way to test it.

Comment: The link above  includes a tool for ngrok that'll punch a hole in your firewall to allow a connection to your dev env.